# Two sites on nginx but one getting all request

Tags: php, python, nginx

I have vps using nginx on that web server I got 2 conf (host1.com,host2.com) files on /etc/nginx/conf.d but 2 domain access to the same site. those site are on different technologies 1 PHP (Apache running on 88 ) and 1 python  (gunicorn running on 5000) both site can be access from outside correctly using those ports.

site 1 conf

```
server{
    listen   80;

    root /var/www/host1.com/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name host1.com;

    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:88;

     }

     location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
     }
}
```

host2 conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name host2.com;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/fundacion.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't know why put a down vote and don't say anything and even read the question :/

Comment: Post your `nginx.conf` followed by the vhost config for each domain. It looks like a config issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Restart nginx.
2. Clear your browser cache.

Comment: Your browser cached content for one of the domains when you have opened it before proper configuration.

Comment: mmmmmmm well I've delete one conf and the other site work ok. I think was about dns server chached or something.  don't you think?

Comment: As I understood from your conf, both domains are on the same IP. So it's unlikely DNS unless you move it from different IP.

Comment: well I need to research that issue. btw Thanks.